# Is this a bug in Method#to_proc? (Ruby 1.8.7)

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8, destructuring, proc-object

Given the following method that takes one argument:

```
def foo(arg); p arg; end
```

I can call it with an empty array:

```
foo([])
# prints []
```

I can also save it as a `Method` object and call *that* with an empty array, with the same result:

```
method(:foo).call([])
# prints []
```

However, if I convert the `Method` object to a `Proc` and call *that* with an empty array, I get an `ArgumentError`:

```
method(:foo).to_proc.call([])
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
#   from (irb):4:in `foo'
#   from (irb):4:in `to_proc'
#   from (irb):10:in `call'
```

I expected it to behave the same as the previous two cases.  Instead, it seems to be behaving as if I'd written `foo(*[])`.  However, if I call it with a *non*-empty array, it *does* behave the way I expected:

```
method(:foo).to_proc.call([1])
# prints [1]
```

So it destructures the argument, but only if the argument happens to be an empty array.  And only if I call `Method#to_proc`.

Is there a gap in my understanding of how `Method` or `Proc` work, or is this a bug?

I'm running Ruby 1.8.7-p299.  I observe the same behaviour in 1.8.6-p399 and 1.8.7-head.  However, I don't see it in 1.9.1-p378: there all three forms print `[]` when called with an empty array.

Comment: Normally I'm skeptical when someone thinks they've found a bug in the language itself, but I see no other explanation for this behavior, especially considering that it works as expected in 1.9. Hopefully someone wiser can enlighten us, cause this has me pretty curious.

Comment: I don’t always find a bug in the language itself, but when I do I’m using Ruby.

Answer (score 13):

This is almost certainly a bug,

I suspect the reason this is happening is that Method#call has arity -1 (Expecting a C array of arguments), and Proc#call has arity -2 (Expecting a Ruby Array of arguments).

There's a further helpful comment in eval.c above the definition of Proc#call that may shed further light on the issue:

/* CHECKME: are the argument checking semantics correct? */

Maybe we should change that to a FIXME :p

Comment: It's fixed in Ruby 1.9, so I think it WAS a bug :)